# Birt runtime in tomcat jdbc connection error

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc, birt

I created a report in Birt 4.4.0 and now want to view the report in the birt runtime in my tomcat 8.0.26.
The report connects to an Oracle database and works fine in the report designer but when I execute it in the birt runtime I get the following exceptions:

```
Sep 10, 2015 1:05:01 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCDriverManager loadExtraDriver
SCHWERWIEGEND: DriverClassLoader failed to load class: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

Sep 10, 2015 1:05:01 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCDriverManager loadExtraDriver
SCHWERWIEGEND: refreshUrlsWhenFail: true
Sep 10, 2015 1:05:01 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCDriverManager loadExtraDriver
SCHWERWIEGEND: driverClassPath: null
Sep 10, 2015 1:05:01 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCDriverManager loadExtraDriver
SCHWERWIEGEND: Registered URLs: 
Sep 10, 2015 1:05:01 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCDriverManager findDriver
WARNUNG: Failed to load JDBC driver class: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
Sep 10, 2015 1:05:01 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCDriverManager loadExtraDriver
SCHWERWIEGEND: DriverClassLoader failed to load class: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

Sep 10, 2015 1:05:01 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCDriverManager loadExtraDriver
SCHWERWIEGEND: refreshUrlsWhenFail: true
Sep 10, 2015 1:05:01 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCDriverManager loadExtraDriver
SCHWERWIEGEND: driverClassPath: null
Sep 10, 2015 1:05:01 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCDriverManager loadExtraDriver
SCHWERWIEGEND: Registered URLs: 
Sep 10, 2015 1:05:01 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCDriverManager findDriver
WARNUNG: Failed to load JDBC driver class: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
Sep 10, 2015 1:05:01 PM org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.ConnectionManager openConnection
SCHWERWIEGEND: Unable to open connection.
org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCException: Cannot load JDBC Driver class: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.

Sep 10, 2015 1:05:01 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCDriverManager loadExtraDriver
SCHWERWIEGEND: DriverClassLoader failed to load class: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

Sep 10, 2015 1:05:01 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCDriverManager loadExtraDriver
SCHWERWIEGEND: refreshUrlsWhenFail: true
Sep 10, 2015 1:05:01 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCDriverManager loadExtraDriver
SCHWERWIEGEND: driverClassPath: null
Sep 10, 2015 1:05:01 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCDriverManager loadExtraDriver
SCHWERWIEGEND: Registered URLs: 
Sep 10, 2015 1:05:01 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCDriverManager findDriver
WARNUNG: Failed to load JDBC driver class: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
Sep 10, 2015 1:05:01 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCDriverManager loadExtraDriver
SCHWERWIEGEND: DriverClassLoader failed to load class: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

Sep 10, 2015 1:05:01 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCDriverManager loadExtraDriver
SCHWERWIEGEND: refreshUrlsWhenFail: true
Sep 10, 2015 1:05:01 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCDriverManager loadExtraDriver
SCHWERWIEGEND: driverClassPath: null
Sep 10, 2015 1:05:01 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCDriverManager loadExtraDriver
SCHWERWIEGEND: Registered URLs: 
Sep 10, 2015 1:05:01 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCDriverManager findDriver
WARNUNG: Failed to load JDBC driver class: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
Sep 10, 2015 1:05:01 PM org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.ConnectionManager openConnection
SCHWERWIEGEND: Unable to open connection.
org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCException: Cannot load JDBC Driver class: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.
```

I put the jdbc .jar in the tomcat's lib folder and in the WEB-INF/lib folder of the birt runtime.
Also, the report uses a connection profile.

Hope someone has an idea.

Comment: Did you restart Tomcat after putting the jar into the application? Does your jdbc.jar contain a classes called `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver`? (to see the contents of a jar file: rename it to .zip and extract it)

Comment: I restarted tomcat multiple times, yes. But no, there is no such file in the .jar .. Do you know why this is the case and what to do with that? And why does it work in the Report Designer .. ?

Comment: I don't know, what your `jdbc.jar` is, but Oracle JDBC driver is usually in an `ojdbcX.jar` (where X is the minimal Java version). See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/default-2280470.html - download one and put it into your `WEB-INF/lib` folder.

Comment: It is in fact an ojdbc jar but oh damn. Jozef Chocholacek, you just reminded me that in Report Designer I have several similar jars linked. I deleted all of them and again added the one that should work. And of course it did ........ probably some conflict between the jars. I mean, the report still doesn't work - I get an OutOfMemoryException, but that I hope I will figure out on my own. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue somehow sorted out in the comments - but for anyone landing on this question:

- you need a jar containing `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver` in your Application
- Search for jars containing that class [in google](https://www.google.com/search?q=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver%20jar&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) and you will probably land at oracle's driver page ([11g release](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/apps-tech/jdbc-112010-090769.html) or [12c release](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/jdbc-drivers-12c-download-1958347.html) or similar). `ojdbc6.jar` or `ojdbc7.jar` is probably what you are looking for.
- for to check, whether you have a correct jar file: rename the jar file to ".zip", extract it, and find `OracleDriver.java` in the folder `oracle/jdbc/driver/`. If it exists, then this jar should help you avoid that ClassNotFound exception